# Indexing Error from loc command with pandas in python. No index in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to print particular columns from a data set that has nine columns. There is no index for the rows in the csv file. I am trying to use pandas as pd and a loc command. It comes up with an indexing error. At the bottom it says too many indexers

I am new to pandas and am playing with it for the first time. So I am not even sure what to try to fix this.

```
import pandas as pd
dfa=pd.read_csv('cars.csv', sep=';')
print(dfa)
print(dfa.columns)
print(dfa.loc['Car', 'Horsepower', 'MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Weight'])
```

I am running this in Jupyter Notebook. As expected, it first prints out a table with just over 400 cars. Then it prints out the column names (without any indexes as far as I can tell). Then it has an error running the loc command. First it says indexing error. Then it says

## we by definition only have the 0th axis...

## no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers

## ugly hack for GH #836

```
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Scottman. Please include sample data and the code that is currently giving you an error. This wil help the folks here that want to give you the assistence you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use:**

```
print(dfa.loc[:,['Car', 'Horsepower', 'MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Weight']])
```

**Reason:**

to `df.loc[]` you have to pass a list with the arguments of columns if you want select more than one:

```
['Car', 'Horsepower', 'MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Weight']
```

If you want get all rows you can use: `:`

**But you always have to specify which rows to select one way or another.**

To more info consult:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Also you can use:

```
dfa[['Car', 'Horsepower', 'MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Weight']]
```